# Is there any security risk on sending JWT token in client side from nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, jwt

I made an API where I have to send jwt token to client side

where I encrypt users `number` and `userID` to token
like

```
var token = jwt.sign({
                      number: number,
                      userID: userID
                  });
```

then i am using `res.send({status :'success' , token : token})` to send token to client.

Is there any security issue on sending token to client side or in assigning `userID` and `number` because these are very crucial data?

Comment: Are you **creating** the token on the client side?  That would be a serious security hole, since then you would have to send your encryption key to the client. Otherwise, what do you mean by "assign users `number` and `userID` to token?"

Comment: no, i am creating the token on the server side in nodejs.

Comment: So what do you mean by that "assign" phrase?

Comment: I regularly send information to the client inside the JWT.  The only security concern I see is that a man-in-the-middle might somehow intercept it.  Assuming it does not contain sensitive information, that's not particularly concerning.  Assuming you validate the token when it's sent back to the server, the client cannot alter it and have it remain valid.

Comment: we really need more info here. How do you sign them, how do you store them on the client side, ...

Comment: @JohannesMerz please see above.

Comment: @ScottSauyet means if client alter the token then he is not able to authenticate.

Comment: thnx for reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Please note that the comments following your question are generally an attempt to gain more information necessary to actually offer an answer.  Please respond in comments or [often better] by editing the question to clarify what's being sought in the comments.)

---

The basic idea of the JWT is that while anyone can read it, it's not valid unless the cryptographic signature part matches a secret known by few as well as matching the contents.  Usually this means that a server holds reference to a salt or to the private part of a public-private key pair.  In the first case, only a server that knows that key can verify the JWT.  In the second one, anyone with access to the public key can verify it, but only a server with the private key can *create* it.

Really secret data should never be included in a JWT, since they are easy to parse.  But because of the above, you can use them as tokens on both the client and server side.  You can put in them basic identity and permissioning information, so long as this does not include sensitive information.  Because they will be revalidated on every call to the server, there are no serious concerns about them being altered by the client.

Of course all this depends on your not creating these with client-side code.  That would void all warranties.